# Swift google map not show

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

follow this code on Xcode9.2

```
@IBOutlet weak var mView: UIView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var mapView: GMSMapView!

var currentLatitude:Double = 0.0
var currentLongtitude:Double = 0.0
var heading = 0.00

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude:
        locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15);

    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
    mapView.delegate = self
    self.mView = mapView
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}
```

if I use

```
self.View = mapView
```

it work perfectly but

```
self.mView = mapView
```

it not work, why?? the mMapview is white.

Comment: you probably have forgotten to add the instance to the current view as subview... at least I can't see that part of your code here at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've put a mapview on a storyboard or xib, you've overwritten it by assigning it with `self.mView = mapView`.  Instead there should already be an instantiated self.mView, and you can change `mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)` to `self.mView.camera = camera`, and all the other instances of `mapView` below to `self.mView`.

If you haven't, you can remove `self.mView` entirely and just work with mapView.  Add in `self.view.addSubview(mapView)` to the bottom of your viewDidLoad and you'll be set.

Answer (score 3):

This line `self.mView = mapView` just change pointer `mView` from Outlet view to MapView, but it doesn't add the MapView as a subview. What you need to do is:

1. Remove mView from Interface Builder. You don't need it at all.
2. Replace `self.mView = mapView` with the following code: `view.addSubview(mapView)`
3. Add all needed constraints. For instance:

   ```
   mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
     mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
     mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
     mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
   ])
   ```

Comment: Your answer helped my.  If you set the uiview's class in the story board to GMSMapView it works as well.